# How to deal with different UIAlertAction handler in same UIAlertController in iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uialertcontroller, uialertaction

I am using Objective-C to write about some `UIAlertController` code.

I have more buttons, but the buttons will show different `UIAlertController`s and deal with different `UIAlertAction` handler .

So I want to create one `UIAlertController`,and `UIAlertAction`.

Like below:

```
-(void) initAlert{
    alertController = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:@"hint" message:@"count down alert" preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];

    doneAction = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"okey" style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault handler:
              ^(UIAlertAction *action) {
    NSLog(@"show log");
    }];
    [alertController addAction:doneAction];
}

-(void) showAlert{
    [self presentViewController:alertController animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

Then I want to using different button `IBAction` to  call the `showAlert` method, and set different `UIAlertController` title, `UIAlertAction` title and deal different `alertAction` handler.

But I encounter some problems.

I call the method in different button like below:

```
- (IBAction)btn1Action:(UIButton *)sender {

    alertController.title = @"controller 1";
    alertController.message = @"message1";

    [self showAlert];
}

- (IBAction)btn2Action:(UIButton *)sender {

    alertController.title = @"controller 2";
    alertController.message = @"message2";

    [self showAlert];
}
```

I don't know how to change the `UIAlertAction` title with the same doneAction, I search some data show the `UIAlertAction` is readyonly property.

So have any other methods to change `UIAlertAction` title? or can we delete the `UIAlertController` `addAction:` method to add other `UIAlertAction`?

And how can I pass different `UIAlertAction` handler to AlertAction for the same `UIAlertController` to use?

Thank you very much.

Comment: I dont think UIAlertController is designed for reusability. You should create different UIAlertController for different alerts.

Answer (score 0):

UIAlertController should not be used multiple times.  Just use a new UIAlertController instance each time you want to pop up the alert.

```
- (IBAction)btn1Action:(UIButton *)sender {

    [self showAlert:@"Controller 1" message:@"Message 1" handler:^(UIAlertAction *action) {
        NSLog(@"btn1Action");
    }];
}

- (IBAction)btn2Action:(UIButton *)sender {

    [self showAlert:@"Controller 2" message:@"Message 2" handler:^(UIAlertAction *action) {
        NSLog(@"btn2Action");
    }];
}

-(void)showAlert:(NSString*)alertTitle message:(NSString*)message handler:(void (^ __nullable)(UIAlertAction *action))handler {
    UIAlertController * alertController = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:alertTitle message:message preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];

    UIAlertAction * doneAction = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"Ok" style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault handler:handler];
    [alertController addAction:doneAction];

    [self presentViewController:alertController animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```